# Bootstrap4 media query directly taken mobile view even file opening on laptop

Tags: css, media-queries, bootstrap-4, responsive

i'm using bootstrap 4 on my new project and my laptop Touch + Mouse enabled windows when i tried to use bootstrap its automatically showing mobile format in desktop. how to solve this? below i attached screenshot

> Note : Bootstrap 3 is working fine. this problem only on bootstrap4

[image]

My Code:

```
  <header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
     <li class="nav-item active">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button">Main button</button>
   </form>
 </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Please no screenshot of code, copy-paste your code so that we can make a working example and analyze where the mistake is.

Comment: @cloned code was added please check

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct HTML as stated in the [documentation of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing

You neglected this class, so it is always collapsed.

It is not enough to just change the CSS from bootstrap 3 to 4 you also have to change the markup quite a bit.